# Add stripplot points to bwplot (Lattice graphics in R)

Tags: r, lattice, bwplot

```
##Example data to illustrate problem:
type=c("grp1","grp2","grp1","grp3","grp3","grp3","grp4")
num=c(1,1,2,4,3,5,1)
cols=c(rep("red",5),"green","red")

library(lattice)
bwplot(num~type)
par(new=T)
stripplot(num~type,col=cols)
```

I like the additional information displayed by the box plot but I need the information conveyed by the coloured points in the strip chart. Obviously par(new=T) doesn't work, so how can I overlay the points onto the box plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `panel` function like this :

```
library(lattice)
bwplot(num~type,panel=function(x,y,...){
    panel.bwplot(x,y,...)
    panel.stripplot(x,y,col=cols,...)
})
```

[image]

Comment: a good answer, though points plotted as "outliers" by `bwplot` would then be plotted again by the `stripplot`. if using `jitter.data=TRUE` for the stripplot, it would appear that there were twice the outliers.

Answer (score 0):

the answer by agstudy is quite good, though as I pointed out in a comment, any outliers plotted by bwplot will also be plotted by stripplot, which could get confusing.

Note this is only an issue if you were using `jitter.data=TRUE` as an option to `stripplot`, otherwise the duplicate points would plot directly over top of one another and you'd never know they were there. If the data had outliers, and you used `jitter.data=TRUE`, you'd see twice as many outliers as you should.

the following approach suppresses the outliers from `bwplot` to avoid this issue:

```
bwstrip <- function(x,y,...){
  panel.stripplot(x,y,col=cols,do.out=FALSE,jitter.data=TRUE,...)
  panel.bwplot(x,y,...)
}
bwplot(lobe.depths,panel=bwstrip)
```