# superimpose barchart with stripplot

Tags: r, panel, lattice

I want to superimpose barchart with stripplot, and use panel paremeter in the xyplot, but it doesn't work. It plots nothing and give out many warnings, such as:

```
1: In order(as.numeric(x)) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In diff(as.numeric(x[ord])) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

The code is here, however it works with the factorial Alternatice and Subject variables, although it plot the bar in a horizontal way:

```
t2 <- data.frame(Alternative = c("FA", "HF", "NO", "HF", "FA", "NO"), 
  AlloOthe = c(50, 80, 20, 80, 80, 20), 
  Subject = rep(c("2001", "2002"), each = 3)
)
t2$Alternative <- as.character(t2$Alternative)
t2$Subject <- as.character(t2$Subject)
library(lattice)
xyplot(AlloOthe ~ Alternative | Subject, data = t2,
  panel = function(x, y) {
    panel.barchart(x, y)
    panel.stripplot(x, y, type = c("p", "l"))
  },
  ylab = "Allocation to Other"
)
```

So does anyone could show me the correct code or to make it work on the right data? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in `lattice` package, but I get your plot by following this post: [Add stripplot points to bwplot (Lattice graphics in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154084/add-stripplot-points-to-bwplot-lattice-graphics-in-r/19154162#19154162), so, I add `...` to the panel function definition and also I replaced `xyplot` by `barchart`.

SO, basically, it looks like:

```r
# Assigning Alternative and Subject as factor
t2$Alternative = as.factor(t2$Alternative)
t2$Subject = as.factor(t2$Subject)

library(lattice)
barchart(AlloOthe ~ Alternative | Subject, data = t2,
         panel = function(x,y,...) {
           panel.barchart(x,y,col=adjustcolor("darkorchid",alpha=.6),...)
           panel.stripplot(x,y,col="lightseagreen",pch=16,size=3,...)
         },
         ylab = "Allocation to Other")
```

And the plot looks like:

[image]

As an alternative, you can use `ggplot` by doing the following:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(t2, aes(x = Alternative, y = AlloOthe, group = Alternative)) +
  facet_grid(.~Subject) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = adjustcolor("darkorchid", alpha = 0.6)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, color = "lightseagreen") +
  ylab("Allocation to Other")
```

And the plot looks like:

[image]

Hope it helps you !

Comment: It seems the `...` in `function(x, y, ...)` and following stamens are necessary for the correct plotting with factorial Alternative as the x variable. And the `barchart` instead of the `xyplot` is the right function to use. Thank you very much. You are so nice to offer both the lattice and ggplot methods here.